# Celery with Django - deployment

Tags: python, django, celery

I am considering using celery in my project. I found a lot of information about how to use it etc. What I am interested in is how to deploy/package my solution.

I need to run two components - django app and then celeryd worker (component that sends emails). For example I would like my django app to use email_ticket task that would email support tickets. I create tasks.py in the django app.

```
@task
def email_ticket(from, message):
...
```

Do I deploy my django app and then just run celeryd as separate process from the same path?

```
./manage.py celeryd ...
```

What about workers on different servers? Deploy whole django application and run only celeryd? I understand I could use celery only for the worker, but I would like to use celerycam and celerybeat.

Any feedback is appreciated. Thanks

Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: Good question.  The accepted answer ("deploy everything") is certainly simple and robust -- but not optimal.  Maybe someone can think of a nice way to distribute only the required code to "worker" machines, while not complicating the whole process too much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is covered in the documentation [here](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/daemonizing.html).  The gist is you need to download some init scripts and setup some config.  Once that's done celeryd will start on boot and you'll be off and running.

Comment: I know about this link. What I am more interested in is project structure. How do I structure my Django app and worker code? Should I create another distribution that contains just django apps needed? For example I don't need templates and media for a worker distribution. I need models though.

Comment: I think it depends on where you are deploying it.  For the stuff I'm working on, it all gets deployed to one web site, so I just put the tasks in the application (my project is broken up into fine-grained applications).  

Then I just deploy the whole thing to the worker nodes.  It's simple and I don't worry about breaking something because I forgot to include it in the worker-node distro.

Comment: I guess that's the way to do it. I will just redeploy my Django app for every worker node and then run worker. Thanks, I appreciate your input.

Comment: Obviously a startup script is preferred, no question there. Does this answer indicate that there are technical deficiencies to just running ./manage.py celeryd?